# Write formatted text(printf style) to a MFC CEdit control, which would display the formatted text in a EditControl?

Tags: mfc, formatting, cedit, editcontrol

I need to display text along with values of variables in a CEdit controlled Edit Control Box. How do I do it ? Currently I'm using SetWindowText(), but that only takes a string...how do I get a formatted string to display in the edit control?

Example: printf("The answer is %d\n",ans) -> how do i print the same message in a Edit Control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CString's [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327(VS.60).aspx) member.

```
CString text;
text.Format(_T("The answer is %d\n"), ans);
edit.SetWindowText(text);
```

Comment: and/or you could derive you own class from CEdit and add a method to do that in one call.
M.